# android sqlite database, null pointer

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get and set info into my database but it keeps returning null.

I tested it and it seems to be something wrong with my `DatabaseHelper` class and how I'm using it. This is my `DatabaseHelper` class. The database itself is already made using a sqlite database manager and is in the assets folder.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/package_name/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "example.db";
private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    }else{


     with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}


  private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){


    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
  }


  private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, 
   SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


       }

   public void setStuff (String columns, String table, String values, String              
   whereclause){
    openDataBase();
    myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
             + table
             + " "+columns
             + " VALUES ('"+values+")" + " WHERE "+whereclause);
    close();

   }

   public ArrayList<String> getStuff (String column, String table, String whereclause){
    ArrayList<String> stuffList = new ArrayList<String>();
    openDataBase();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT "+column +
            " FROM " +table
            + " WHERE "+whereclause,
            null);
    int index = c.getColumnIndex(column);
     if (c != null) {
         if (c.isFirst()) {
                 do {

                         String stuff = c.getString(index).toString();
                         results.add(data);
                 } while (c.getString(index)!=null);
         }
     }
     close();
     return stuffList;


}


   @Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


}
```

Next my class that actually tries to use this database helper is for example, my `PersonDBController` class, which is in turned used in my signUp activity, where i just call the method with the parameters.

```
        public class PersonDBController {
            private DatabaseHelper d;
            private Person p;   


                public String getFirstname(int userIDnum) {
                        ArrayList<String> fn = 
                                                      d.getStuff("firstname", 
                                                      "people", "userIDnum     
                                                       ="+userIDnum);
                        String result = fn.get(0);
                        return result;
                    }
```

Thats just one of many methods in that class. However, this doesn't do the job properly. When called in an activity - say on a button click to set or get stuff it returns a null pointer exception.

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: You need to boil this down to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the issue and post it here. Remarkably, when doing this you'll often find your mistake. Dumping all your code here and asking "what's wrong" generally won't garner much help.

Comment: If you get a nullpointerexception then you should give us the stack trace. It would make it easier to find the issue without going through all the code.

Comment: for example there is "with our database." in the code that is outside of the syntax

Comment: what is this from the code?! -> "     with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();"

Comment: basically use LogCat to keep track of which methods are failing, that would be a great place to start

Answer (score -1):

You're probably never initializing `d`. Check your code, do you have something like the following anywhere in it?

```
d = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

If not, that's probably where you issue is.